# How to search td element for part of text and replace entire element with a predefined jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a jQuery that can search the page for something like:

```
<td> 235 2nd St, San Francisco, CA 94105, United States, QJP3+J5 The East Cut, San Francisco, CA, USA </td>
```

Find "QJP3+J5"

Replace the entire td to be:

```
<td> Apple, Inc. </td>
```

Where "Apple, Inc." is already predefined in my jQuery, not something like maps API or something.

Your prompt help is appreciated,
Best regards.

Comment: Maybe this will work. `$("td:contains('QJP3+J5')").text('Apple, Inc.')`. Please consider showing us what you have tried.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/MHDwebs/gw61kcy4/18/ but doesn't work :(

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks! it now works :) I figured out I must add the <table>, <tbody> and <tr> tags in the JSFiddle to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it does. Problem is that if your td is not inside a table, then it will not be rendered as a td.
https://jsfiddle.net/gp0d4vh3/